# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dropdown on my website doesn't open on mobile devices. I've followed many tips and tricks posted on the web but still unable to find a workaround!

This is my html:

```
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
   <ul class="nav-menu">
     <li class="dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown" >
        <button style="padding: 0 8px 10px 8px; font-face: sans-serif;color:#fff; font-weight: 700;font-size: 13px;text-transform: uppercase;opacity: 1;background-color: Transparent;border: 0pt" data-toggle="collapse" >About</button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 0 8px 10px 8px; width: 15px;font-face: sans-serif;color:#fff; font-weight: 700;font-size: 13px;text-transform: uppercase;opacity: 1;background-color: Transparent;border: 0pt">
              <li><a style="color:#fff" tabindex="-1" href="{{ url_for('main.about') }}#who">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a style="color:#fff" tabindex="-1" href="{{ url_for('main.about') }}#team">Team</a></li>
              <li><a style="color:#fff" tabindex="-1" href="{{ url_for('main.faq') }}">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a style="color:#fff" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZLNAHYpL14">Demo</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS imports:

```
  <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS:

```
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: JQuery is needed to bootstrap work.

Comment: I've used  `<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Check Your link properly linked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Jquery to your script section.. bootstrap required to work well..

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: When I use this, the navbar is not visible in mobile and is always open on desptop

Comment: I think something is wrong with the navbar, if i remove id=navbar-menu-container the dropdown comes at the top (not left) and opens on mobile

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v4.2.1

Comment: Can you give me the console messages.. i think there some thing in your element's position.. maybe the click did not targeting the menu..

Comment: nothing's being printed on console. I cant add css here but it is picked from https://bootstrapmade.com/bizpage-bootstrap-business-template/

Comment: I seen, its working well in that example,, okay if you did not making any change in that CSS add this Jquery full version, should work..
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>